# AdvertisingManager.advertisingId on WP 8.1 with a WP 8.0 application?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, system.reflection

I have a WP 8.0 application.

When it runs on a WP 8.1 device, is there a way for me to retrieve (through reflection or something) the value of:

```
Windows.System.UserProfile.AdvertisingManager.AdvertisingId;
```

Or do I need to make 2 different applications, one for WP 8.0 (for obsolete phones) and a second one for WP8.1 (to get this AdvertisingId)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var type = Type.GetType("Windows.System.UserProfile.AdvertisingManager, Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime");
return type != null ? (string) type.GetProperty("AdvertisingId").GetValue(null, null) : "";
```

Comment: Can you add some additional context or documentation explaining how this answered your question?

Comment: This code compiles on a WP8.0 app (the line in the question wasn't). And when you run this WP8.0 app on a WP8.1 phone, you get the desired value. I took the idea of reflection from http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Use_new_tiles_on_Windows_Phone_apps_using_reflection and apparently that's the way to go with most new features with Microsoft Windows.